# Past perfect and present simple in one sentence

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

Can I use past present and present simple in one sentence?
For example, can I say “It is unfair because I had never received those negative comments before”?

Comment: "I had never received..." is *Past **Perfect*** (where "I **have** received..." is ***Present** Perfect*). It's unlikely to be sensible to mix "It **is** unfair..." with "...because I **had** never..." because the initial Present Tense establishes "now, time of speaking" as the "current reference time", but the following Past Perfect clause implies a reference time *in the past*.

Comment: Note that English is usually flexible about the tense used to refer to things that "originate" (were true) in the past, but still relevant to the present. So *"I think it **is** unfair that they sacked me"* is at least as likely as *"I think it **was** unfair that they sacked me".* For the reason given above, your exact example is unlikely, but *in the right context* (say, established prior context fully focused on that time in the past when the *still aggrieved* speaker first experienced negativity), it could be perfectly natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine tenses in one sentence given the appropriate context (which can probably be said about most constructs in English). For example:

> I can't believe they fired me over a few negative comments! It's unfair because I had never received those negative comments before. Even if I had, it's still not a valid reason to let me go. I have been writing my appeal, and I will submit it on Tuesday.